# What are the derivatives of the distance between a curve and an infinitesimal line approximation of the curve?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Consider $r(t)=(x(t),y(t))$ where $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are infinitely often differentiable real functions.

Let $[0,1]\ni s\mapsto(u_{t_0}(s),v_{t_0}(s))$ be a parametrization of the line segment between $r(0)$ and $r(t_0)$.

Let $P$ be the distance to the line segment from the point on that curve $r(t)$ that maximizes the distance, i.e:

$P(t_0)=\underset{{\large t\,\boldsymbol{\in}\,[0,t_0]}}{\max}
\underset{{\large s\,\boldsymbol{\in}\,[0,1]}}{\min}
\sqrt{(u_{t_0}(s)-x(t))^2+(v_{t_0}(s)-y(t))^2}$

How to derive expressions for the derivatives $P'(0)$, $P''(0)$, etc... (computed as limits from above) in terms of the derivatives of $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ at $t=0$?

I think $P'(0)=0$, but I can't see how to derive it

Comment: The equation makes no sense; the right-hand side isn't a point. I think you mean $P(t_0)=r(\hat t(t_0))$ with $\hat t(t_0)=\operatorname{argmax} \ldots$.

Comment: You have

$$
\frac{\partial P(t_0)}{\partial t_0}=\frac{\partial r(\hat t(t_0))}{\partial t_0}=\frac{\partial\hat t}{\partial t_0}\dot r(\hat t(t_0))\;.$$

The second factor goes to $\dot r(0)$ for $t_0\to0$. I'd expect the first factor to go to 
$\frac12$ (based on a second-order approximation of the curve near $t=0$), so I think you'll find $P'(0)=\frac12\dot r(0)$.